# Migration from Adjacency List to Closure Tables

Tags: mysql, closures

I have an Adjacency List relations in MySQL groups table.

```
| id | parent |
```

Lately found that queries work slower each day and have decided to migrate to Closure Tables (groups_connection MySQL table):

```
| parent | child | level |
```

I am totally stucked on this for over week. Can somebody help with this?
Tested lots of scripts. For the moment, got nothing to do with it.